# How to send the username of the message sender to the dialogflow bot in telegram?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, telegram

I connected the dialogflow bot to the telegram chat and it responds to user messages but without specifying their names and periodically determines random words from the text of the message as the user names.
How to set up a dialogflow bot in the telegram chat so it receives not only messages, but the message sender user names too?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using Dialogflow with Telegram, Telegram already provides you a unique id for every Telegram user. Try to output the body request from Telegram and then catch that uniqueid value.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this in the Dialogflow interface!

Comment: Check the request that comes when Telegram session starts. You can found there.

Answer (score 0):

I checked through the telegram webhook - the username is indeed sent to the bot with the message.
Probably the problem is in the telegram integration code of the dialogflow-es bot.